Problem accepting Erc20 platform transaction
Hi i transfer trump coin between my exchangers wallet end wallet is Bitunix i did all of them right because of updating bitunix exchanger my transfer show success at first wallet or etherscan.io but after 5days my wallet is zero out of money i ask support help me they didn't do it i ask them give private key of my wallet i will solve this problem by myself again they don't do anything please someone help me to solve it and i get my token thanks
My email addresse:
Hossein-1995@live.com
Telegram id:@Hossein19956
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x239bab9eea5496113a30b493ec3ea19ab7fa687dcedfd15ef4a55f41d2fa095e
